# Fetch ID in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
//DB Connection
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo "<input type=submit name=submit id='".$row["name"]."add' value='".$row["name"]." +' ></br>"; 
echo "<input type=submit name=submit id='".$row["name"]."sub' value='".$row["name"]." -' ></br>";

/*
above code will like this in runtime -- just an example
echo "<input type=submit name=submit id='customeradd' value='customer +' ></br>"; 
echo "<input type=submit name=submit id='customersub' value='customer -' ></br>";
echo "<input type=submit name=submit id='studentadd' value='student +' ></br>"; 
echo "<input type=submit name=submit id='studentsub' value='student -' ></br>";
*/

}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

// Fetch ID here : according to this perform following operations
// if customer clicks on customer + " update  customeradd set id=id+1 ; "
// if customer clicks on customer - " update  customeradd set id=id-1 ; "
// if customer clicks on student + " update  studentadd set id=id+1 ; " & so on

}

?>
```

The above code consists of 2 buttons with different value & ID's. These ID's and values are generated at run time through the database.

I am interested in ID (val1) where user is interested in value (+). 
I searched for different solutions whether answer will be like change value=val1 but i dont want to show it to user.

Is there any way to do that?

**Edit :**

Suppose DB has 10 values. So here my script will generate 20 buttons. For which i already have whose 20 tables created in db. I dont want to keep value same as my db name due to some concern.

Here its not possible for me to check `if(isset($_POST['name']))` for each name. Thats why i am thinking about keeping `name=submit` with different `id`.

Comment: *This ID's and values are generated * - it would be better to grenerate diff name

Comment: But they can see all of your html code, even the id.  Why are you trying to hide the value?

Comment: @splash58 : Thanks for response. I can also go for different 'name'. Can you plz share ur idea with me ?

Comment: `<input type=submit name=submit_plus id=val1 value=+>
<input type=submit name=submit_minus id=val2 value=->` and `if(isset($_POST['submit_plus']))` ....

Comment: @Rob : its something when user clicks on + i want to insert value in `val1` table & when user clicks on - i want to insert value in `val2` table in database. I dont want to disclose my table name with user.

Comment: use `$_POST['input name here']` and don't forget to enclose HTML attribute values in double quotes

Comment: @splash58: it's two different submit buttons. only the one which got clicked would have its value submitted anyways, so this technically correct.

Comment: @MarcB i see, but how understand which was pressed, if they have the same name?

Comment: by the value. `if ($_POST['submit'] == '+') { val1 was pressed }`

Comment: @MarcB Cool.  i didn't thought about there values :)

Comment: Guys , sorry for inconvenience. I have updated by question to make it more clear.

Comment: *Scope Creep Alert*. You definitely don't want that many things to have the same name in the same page. Use PHP to give each button a unique name.

Comment: @JayBlanchard : do you have any idea to implement this by some different method ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method=post>
<input type="submit" name="increment" value="+">
<input type="submit" name="decrement" value="-">
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['increment']))
{
    // add one
}elseif(isset($_POST['decrement']))
{
     // subtract one
}
?>
```

I would use different names for each one.

Comment: why? `if ($_POST['submit'] == '+") { val1 pressed } else { val2 pressed }`

Comment: Why what? PS: Yours will assume val2 was pressed even when nothing was, or some other circumstance.

Comment: well, true enough, easy to `else if == '-'` and whatnot too... just demonstrating that putting in different names is NOT required.

Comment: Thanks for respnse. I have updated my question. Can you please share ur views on updated question ?

Answer (score 1):

All of the values are in the `$_POST` array, just make the names unique:

```
<body>
<form method=post>
<input type=submit name=val1 id=val1 value=+>
<input type=submit name=val2 id=val2 value=->
</form>
</body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['val1']))
{
    // The values are also in the $_POST array.
    echo $_POST['val1'];
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for respnse. I have updated my question. Can you please share ur views on updated question ?